# c++ output increasing numbers

Tags: c++, arrays

Hi I have an array of share prices but I only want to output them as they increase.

For example if I have 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5, etc. I only want to print 1,2,3,4.

I have tried setting a temporary max and min but still can't get it.
Now I only have this:

```
for(int h = 0; h < max; h++)
        {

            if(v3[h].getPrice() > 0)
            {
            ofile <<  v[h].getPrice() << ", ";
            }
        }
```

Comment: So your code prints the prices greater than zero.  Where is the logic where you try to do what you asked for?  Did you attempt it?

Comment: One `std::unique` call will do well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Assign your vector
    int a[] = {1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,1,3};
    vector<int> vec(a, a+15);

    // Sort before calling unique
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    // Impose only one of each
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    it = unique(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    vec.resize( distance(vec.begin(),it) );

    // Output your vector
    for( vector<int>::iterator i = vec.begin(); i!= vec.end(); ++i)
        cout << (*i) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/56KtHd)

The `sort` is necessary for `unique` to work.

Comment: If would replace the `vec.resize` call with `vec.erase(it, vec.end());`

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[15] = {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5};
    for (int i=0; i<15; i+=3)
    {
        cout << a[i] <<",";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Increment the counter 3 times in the loop " for(int h=0;h < max; h+=3){} ".